# transform array of arrays inserting nulls, Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am receiving data in this way:

```
  [Sun Jan 01 2006 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), 8.605613643557573]
  [Mon Jan 01 2007 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), 4.639263458390814]
  [Tue Jan 01 2008 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), 3.690424190442011]
  [Thu Jan 01 2009 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), -6.068362055704255]
  [Fri Jan 01 2010 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), 0.011317380895792274]
  [Sat Jan 01 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), 3.9984661908088825]
  [Sun Jan 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), 2.4211622308876173]
  [Tue Jan 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), -1.5740599423273804]
  [Wed Jan 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), 2.6624793033769967]
  [Thu Jan 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), 1744.9379869455643]
  ["err", NaN]
  [Wed Jan 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), 3417.1886283181875]
  [Wed Jan 01 2025 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), 3331.7059850696196]
  [Tue Jan 01 2030 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), 3237.940431993671]
```

And I'm trying to make a dataset to look like this:

```
  [Sun Jan 01 2006 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), 8.605613643557573, 0]
  [Mon Jan 01 2007 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), 4.639263458390814, 0]
  [Tue Jan 01 2008 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), 3.690424190442011, 0]
  [Thu Jan 01 2009 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), -6.068362055704255, 0]
  [Fri Jan 01 2010 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), 0.011317380895792274, 0]
  [Sat Jan 01 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), 3.9984661908088825, 0]
  [Sun Jan 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), 2.4211622308876173, 0]
  [Tue Jan 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), -1.5740599423273804, 0]
  [Wed Jan 01 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), 2.6624793033769967, 0]
  [Thu Jan 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST), 1744.9379869455643, 0]
  ["err", NaN]
  [Wed Jan 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST),0 , 3417.1886283181875]
  [Wed Jan 01 2025 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST),0 , 3331.7059850696196]
  [Tue Jan 01 2030 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST),0 , 3237.940431993671]
```

Is there a way to do this by looking at the index of "err" ?

Comment: You can use `Array.map` and check whether `element[0] === "err"`

Comment: `for (const el of data) if (el[0] != "err") el.push(0)`?

Comment: I need to add nulls in the second column after I reach that index, that's where im stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a variable to track if `"err"` has been found, and use that information to decide where to `.splice()` the new member.

```
var found = false
for (const a of data) {
  if (!found && a[0] === "err")
    found = true;
  else
    a.splice(found ? 1 : 2, 0, 0);
}
```

---

If you want to make use of the index where the `err` was found, then use `.entries()` on the array and change the `found` variable to store the index instead.

```
var foundIdx = -1;
for (const [idx, a] of data.entries()) {
  const found = foundIdx !== -1;

  if (!found && a[0] === "err")
    foundIdx = idx;
  else
    a.splice(found ? 1 : 2, 0, 0);
}

console.log("the err index was", foundIdx);
```

Comment: This is really cool, is there a way to know the index of a[0] === "err" inside if statement?

Comment: I'd like to delete that line after this is done, tho not asked first I'd really appreciate it (:

Comment: @JaimeFH: Yes, change the loop to `for (const [i, a] of data.entries) {` and the `i` will be the index which you can use in the `if` where the `"err"` was found. Don't forget to add curly braces to the `if` if you're going to have more statements than is currently shown.

Comment: Couldn't get that to work, ended up creating a var like this:  `const idx = data.findIndex((el) => el[0] === "err")`  and comparing it like `if (idx !== -1) ...`, thanks for the help

Comment: @JaimeFH: Odd. Did you try the example I added to the answer above? It should work and it prevents you from iterating twice.

Comment: Yes, when I try ´data.entries()´  , I get an error ´"IterableIterator" is not an array type or a string type´

Comment: @JaimeFH: Which JS implementation are you using? I do see an error in my code though. The comparison for `found` is wrong, so I'll fix that. But otherwise it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the index of the error using [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```
var errIndex = data.findIndex(el => el[0] == "err");
assert(errIndex != -1);
return data.map(([date, val], i) => {
  if (i < errIndex)
    return [date, val, 0];
  if (i > errIndex)
    return [date, 0, val];
  return ["err", NaN] // or whatever
);
```

Alternatively you might want to do

```
var it = data.values();
for (const el of it) {
  if (el[0] == "err") break;
  el.push(0);
}
for (const el of it) {
  el.splice(1, 0, 0);
}
```